# Rails Bootstrap Tooltips Don't Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Rails 4.2 and Bootstrap 3 site I'm working on.

I'm trying to get tooltips to work on links and they aren't working. I've read what Bootstrap says to do [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

Here is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require_tree .

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Here is the code I have on my page:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Item Description">Item 35086743</a>
```

I have the raw bootstrap files (js, css) in the respective directories in the assets directory (I'm not using a gem).

I've looked at a few other items here on Stackoverflow, but none of those items have helped either.

All assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check your header and see if the bootstrap files really got loaded. Furthermore, I suggest you use the following gem: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Comment: +1 on Phil's suggestion... seems to me like the bootstrap's javascript isn't being loaded. You will need to require them in your application.js manually since you aren't using any gem to get it to work

Comment: I've used the bootstrap gem you mention in past projects and ran into other issues. When I inspect the element and reload the page after adding //=require bootstrap.min it appears that the bootstrap.min.js file is loading

Comment: Did u try to run that script from web dev tools (f12) after page loads?